# SEO friendly dynamic url in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I search into google many times but didn't get any suitable result for that..

I have a dynamic `url` in c#  Something like

> http://192.168.10.120:81/ImgDetails.aspx?id=5702&icod=100-106083

Title of the image is like

> Man having breakfast

I want the URL like the following example

http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-senior-man-looking-out-over-hopi-point-grand-canyon-arizona-focus-73496317.html

So can i rewrite my dynamic URL into the same please help.

Comment: Use routing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET version 4 or above the following might help.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Easy-Steps-to-URL-2f792901

Comment: I want to convert the URL into `.Html`